# NoServiceFoundForGivenName when stop another server's service with invoke-command

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2, powershell-remoting, windows-server-2019

I have 2 windows server, Server1 (now 2019) and ServerUpdate (2012 R2)
On each server I have an admin user named: AdminUpdate with the same password.

Im currently switching my Server1  windows server 2012 R2 for a windows server 2019. The following powershell code was working #1 before the switch.

I try to run this powershell on ServerUpdate to stop aservice on Server1

```
# Obtient une instance du mot passe sécurisé
$passwordCred = ConvertTo-SecureString *SomePassword* -AsPlainText -Force

# Obtient les crédentials
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList AdminUpdate, $passwordCred

# Effectue le Stop sur le service
invoke-command -computerName *Server1Ip* -scriptBlock { 
    # Effectue le stop en local
    Stop-Service -Name $args[0] -Force
} -credential $cred -ArgumentList *someServiceName*
```

For some reason I always got this error:

```
'*someServiceName*'.
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (*someServiceName*:String) [Stop-Service], ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoServiceFoundForGivenName,Microsoft.PowerShell. 
   Commands.StopServiceCommand
    + PSComputerName        : *Server1Ip*
```

But if i try directly this, its return the service

```
Get-Service -ComputerName *Server1Ip* -Name *someServiceName*
```

I have check this https://blog.netspi.com/powershell-remoting-cheatsheet/

I have the PSRemoting Enable
I put the sevice WinRM auto
I put my Server1 ip in the Trustedhosts on the ServerUpdate and same for the Server1, I put the ServerUpdate ip in the Trustedhosts

Did someone know why I got this error?

Comment: Can you check if `$args[0]` inside the scriptblock actually gets the name of the service? Try `Invoke-Command -ComputerName *Server1Ip* -ScriptBlock { 
    param($ServiceName)
    # Effectue le stop en local
    Stop-Service -Name $ServiceName -Force
} -Credential $cred -ArgumentList 'someServiceName'`

Comment: @Theo I have the same error :/ . I also try to make an Write-Output $args[0] and its return the expected value